# Laravel PHP & Mysql: Convert table data into columns and rows by counting the instances of a string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a database table (around 10000+ rows) with data like this.

```
tags_id   tag_name  contact   date_applied
   1        happy     12         2019-04-01
   2        sad       67         2019-04-01
   1        happy     96         2019-04-01
   3        angry     56         2019-04-02
   2        happy     43         2019-04-02
```

Now I need this table to look like this.

```
date_applied  happy  sad  angry
 2019-04-01     2     1     0
 2019-04-02     1     0     1
```

How can I achieve this in Laravel / PHP? I need to save this to either another database table or a file.

Comment: try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran the database we are using is mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below query.

```
DB::table('table_name')
->select(DB::raw("
    sum( case when tag_name = 'happy' then 1 else 0 end) as happy
    ,sum( case when tag_name = 'sad' then 1 else 0 end) as sad
    ,sum( case when tag_name = 'angry' then 1 else 0 end) as angry
"), 'date_applied')
->groupBy('date_applied');
```

Or you can use direct query

```
select date_applied
,sum( case when tag_name = 'happy' then 1 else 0 end) as happy
,sum( case when tag_name = 'sad' then 1 else 0 end) as sad
,sum( case when tag_name = 'angry' then 1 else 0 end) as angry
from table
group by date_applied
```

For dynamic tags,

```
$tags = Tag::all();
$selectQuery = '';
foreach($tags as $tag){
    $selectQuery.="sum( case when tag_name = '".$tag->tag_name."' then 1 else 0 end) as ".$tag->tag_name.",";
}

DB::table('table_name')
->select(DB::raw($selectQuery."date_applied")
->groupBy('date_applied')
```

Comment: Thanks! it seems correct but is there anyway I can make the tag_name dynamic, there are a lot of tags in that table and can't really do this statically

Comment: is your tag stored in any table?

Comment: no other table that I can access that has the list of tags, I only get tags from that table itself